# Power BI IF, AND Function

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm attempting to write a DAX Formula that tells me the number of days that a case is opened and closed, and from there to then tell me which case was closed above the average closure day (187) and what was closed below average.

However I need an additional ask within the IF formula to included Cases with Status as Completed.
I tried the following DAX, but this appears to ignoring the Status Completed

```
Avg to Closure = IF(And(Sheet1[# Days To Close]>=187, Sheet1[Status]"Completed","Above Average","Below Average")
```

Here is an example of my table.
[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOD9Y.png)

I need a formula to ignore the 2nd account as this currently has a status as open. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want a measure that calculates average *days to close*.

```
daytoclose_avg =
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(Sheet1[# Days To Close])
)
```

No, you can build some intelligence for the `Avg to Closure`. Meaning that it compares the row's days to close to the whole average and returns "Below" or "Above" based on this logic.

```
Avg To Closure =
VAR avg_allcompleted =
CALCULATE(
    [daystoclose_avg],
    ALL(Sheet1),
    Sheet1[Status] = "Completed"
)
VAR avg_row = [daystoclose_avg]
RETURN
IF(
    avg_row > avg_allcompleted,
    "Above Average",
    "Below Average"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I’ve tried this out but doesn’t give me what I am after. 
For example under Status “Open”, the Avg To Closure is still showing as below average, I would have thought that this would have been blank or something considering status is open instead of completed so should be ignored?